# Regex: Get specific string without characters before and after the string

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm looking for `$AS0170S` in a string:

```
{| class="wikitable" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1"
|-
| width="150" valign"top" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:right;" | '''Name:'''
| $AS0170S
|- style="background-color:white;"
| valign="top" style="vertical-align:top; text-align:right;" | '''Text:'''
| Prozeduren für Barcodes ASp170
|-
|}
```

There may be a newline or spaces around `$AS0170S`, but I want to get this value without these whitespace characters.

I use `replacAll("(?i)" + emxapleValue);`

Comment: Could you please clarify? The `\\bASBHJ\\b` matches the `ASBHJ` as a whole word, BTW.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But i doesn't fit for me: https://regex101.com/r/qM7bH3/1

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? [It matches `ASBHJ` ok](https://regex101.com/r/qM7bH3/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, why do I need to add a "g"?

Comment: I do not know if you need to add `g`. I do not know what you need. Say, you have `"JAS ASBHJ GDJ"`. What is the output you need?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need `"ASBHJ"` and i doesn't match the third example.

Comment: Which example is the third? `ABSHJ`? But it is not `ASBHJ`. Please reconsider your requirements and test cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh sry, my mistake.

Comment: So, is the `\b` around `ASBHJ` the only thing you needed?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, it doesn't really work https://regex101.com/r/qM7bH3/4

Comment: You do not need `\b` before `$` as `$` is already a non-word character: [`(?i)\$AS0170S\b`](https://regex101.com/r/qM7bH3/5)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But I need a regex where I get a string without characters before and after the string. A whitespace or a new line can be before or after the string.

Comment: Can there be a comma, too? If not, I believe you just need `"(?<=^|\\s)\\$AS0170S(?=\\s|$)"`. See [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qM7bH3/6).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, thats perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
"(?<=^|\\s)\\$AS0170S(?=\\s|$)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qM7bH3/6)

The lookarounds `(?<=^|\s)` and `(?=\s|$)` make sure that the `$AS0170S` is encloses with whitespaces or is at the beginning or end of the string. The lookarounds are zero-width assertions that do not consume characters (=do not put the matched text into the matched text buffer), so the whitespaces are not returned as part of the match.